# Не работает fancybox после ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, fancybox

Этот код работает при загрузке страницы

```
  $('.fancybox_gallery .fancybox').fancybox({
    afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
      parentBlock = $("[data-fancybox = '"+current.opts.fancybox+"']").closest(".fancybox_gallery");
      curDescript = parentBlock.find(".fancybox:eq("+ current.index +") .descript").html();
      if( $(".fancybox-slide--current .slide_info").length != 1 ) {
        $(".fancybox-slide--current").append("<div class='slide_info'></div>");
        $(".fancybox-slide--current .slide_info").html(curDescript);
      }
  }
 });
```

В WordPress делается фильтрация постов через ajax.
После того как через ajax запрос вставляется элемент .fancybox_gallery .fancybox, этот код перестает работать. Как решить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ, это заново вызвать Ваш скрипт. Так как при выполнения метода "fancybox()" происходит копирование ссылки на элементы и дальше он работает только с ним.